# Mediainfo - Analyze media track starting at a custom time

Tags: video, mediainfo

As I understand Mediainfo analyzes video from the metadata of the first few frames. Is there a way to get Mediainfo to analyze the video starting at a certain time? 
If this is not attainable, can I do it with the C++ source code?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, [I already answered](https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/discussion/297609/thread/e87fd0f4/). 
For the second question, all is always doable with source code, it is only a matter of time for coding ;-), so I don't understand the purpose of the question. Don't hesitate to provide your modification when you implement it.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo